# Cesium real-time uses local time instead of UTC

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset, cesiumjs

I'm working with czml and Cesium. However when I load czml data using

```
Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml)
```

The Cesium real-time button on the animation widget pulls from the browser timezone, as opposed to UTC. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Hi.  It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking about.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then come back and edit your question to include details that would help someone understand your question.  For example, consider that we might not know what the Cesium real-time button animation widget is, or what Cesium is at all.  Any code you can show or examples you can link to will help us help you.  Thanks.

Comment: Cesium should always use UTC, not local time, and it says so right on the animation widget by default.  These are somewhat user-configurable, does your setup include any such customizations?  Can you post a screenshot (by editing your question) of the anim widget showing the wrong thing?  What timezone is your browser in, and what's the UTC offset?

Comment: Also, when you load CZML as shown in your question, the animation widget will reset to the start time of the CZML.  The first few lines of CZML often include a `document` object with a `clock` configuration, can you edit your question to include that information too?  Is it specified in local or UTC in the CZML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CZML contains clock settings which are applied after loading the data source.

Try adding the following to your CZML:

```
"step": "SYSTEM_CLOCK"
```

You can also specify that the viewer automatically ignores clocks provided by the data-source:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {automaticallyTrackDataSourceClocks : false});
```